# cambiar nombre de una clase dentro de un metodo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();
var slides

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 4seconds
}

function plusSlides(position) {
    slideIndex +=position;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    else if(slideIndex<1){slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }

    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  

}

function currentSlide(index) {
    if (index> slides.length) {index = 1}
    else if(index<1){index = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }

    slides[index-1].style.display = "block";  

}
```

Comment: Saludos, tu pregunta esta mal formulada debes explicar que tienes, que quieres y como piensas hacerlo. De esta manera te entendemos mejor y te ayudamos mas rapido.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: vengo empezando, como puedo comunicarme con alguien para que me ayude por medio de correo ?

Comment: no es por medio de correo @chrisbmx20 es que redactes mejor tu pregunta, pues no es clara

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a cambiar el nombre de una `clase` de `HTML` puedes usar `JQUERY` dentro de una función de la siguiente manera:

HTML:

```
<p class="antigua">Hola</p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function cambiarClase(){
     $(".antigua").attr('class', 'nueva');

}
```

Comment: hola graciias pero no se bien como hacer eso